# Use .ToDictionary to return another Dictionary type

Tags: c#, dictionary, casting, linq-to-objects

I have a dictionary and it's type is `Dictionary<int, fooClass> fooDic` and another dictionary is `Dictionary<int, string> barlist` and I'm using this linq to return result

```
var foobarList = fooDic.Where(kvp => 
       !barlist.ContainsKey(((fooClass)kvp.Value)._fooID))
       .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);
```

This will return result of fooDic type. But I need to type cast output as `barlist(Dictionary<int, string>)` type. How?

Comment: Well, a `fooClass` is not a `string` (I assume) so what kind of converting/casting do you want to perform?

Comment: Yes J you are right fooClass is some Class..i need output as Dictionary<int, string> type...

Comment: So how would you go about converting fooClass to a string?

Comment: Yes, and I asked how you suppose to transform a `fooClass` to a `string`. What do you want to go in the `string` part? =)

Comment: Ah, sorry..My mistake in asking question...You are right..You gave me some idea...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a rather simple transformation, the key is the last part of your

```
var foobarList = fooDic.Where(kvp => 
    !barlist.ContainsKey(((fooClass)kvp.Value)._fooID))
    .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);
```

statement. Where you currently use `kvp => kvp.Value`, you substitute that for `kvp => kvp.Value._foobarValue`.

Edited for "full" solution in accordance with OP's comments.

Comment: yes, you are right...Thanks +1 for your idea..I was supposed to do it as ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value._foobarValue); It should be like that...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your class Foo looks like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string SomeValue { get; set; }
    public int SomeOtherStuff { get; set; }
}
```

Create a new dictionary:

```
var fooDict = new Dictionary<int, Foo>() {
    {0, new Foo() {SomeOtherStuff=10, SomeValue="some value"} },
    {1, new Foo() {SomeOtherStuff=15, SomeValue="some other value"} }
};
```

Convert it:

```
Dictionary<int, string> stringDict = 
    fooDict.ToDictionary(x=> x.Key, x=> x.Value.SomeValue);  //<- note x.Value.SomeValue
```

stringDict will now contain:

```
{0, "some value"}, {1, "some other value"}
```

Comment: If J. Steen's answer managed to help you with your problem you should upvote and accept his answer. :)